# What is the degree of following differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Can you help me find the degrees of the following differential equations?
>   $$\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2 + \frac{1}{dy/dx}=2$$
>   $$x+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)= \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2 }$$
>   $$\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^3-4\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2+7y= \sin x$$

Please offer your assistance

Thank you :D

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: Did 16 problems and got these wrong.

Comment: Degree of a differential equation is the degree of the highest order derivative when expressed as a differential equation

Comment: Right, so what do you think are the orders of these?

Comment: i got these : 2, 1, 3

Comment: Waiting for an answer....

Comment: Do you mean to write $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ or $\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2$?

Comment: no. the forst one is a second derivative and the next s the sqare of a first derivative

Comment: I know that, but the degrees are different.  In my comment, the degree of the first is 2 and the degree of the second is 1.  If you mean $\left( \frac{dy}{dx} \right)^n$ in your equations, then the degree of each of those equations is 1.

Comment: In my book, first one is not 2 and second is not 1.

Comment: If the book answers are different from 1, then you must have copied the equations wrong.  As you have written them, all of your equations have degree 1.

Comment: Wrong, all the equations have order 1. Degree varies. Equations are copied accurately. Triple checked

Comment: My mistake, I was thinking of order.  In that case, I don't see why your answers are incorrect ...

Comment: $$\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2 + \frac{1}{dy/dx}=2$$=$$\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2 + \frac{dx}{dy}=2$$ Which degree should i take?

Comment: what about $x'^{-2}+x'$

Comment: My answers would be 3, 2, 3.  Were those the correct answers?

Comment: First two are corrext. How did u get it? please post as an answer

Comment: Got the answer for the first one. Multiple throught by dy/dx. Thank you mike

Comment: The second one I squared both sides to make it into a polynomial.

Comment: But what should the correct answer for the 3rd one be?

Answer (score 1):

I looked up the definition of "degree of ODE" on Wikipedia.  It does seem to me to be both a useless and not well-defined concept.

But I tried to write the ODE as a polynomial in the highest order derivative.  The first one I multiply by $dy/dx$ to get a cubic in $dy/dx$.  The second one I squared to make it a polynomial of order 2 in $dy/dx$.  I cannot see why the third one isn't 3.